# How can I debug the dbt error that says "Database error while listing schemas in database XYZ"?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, fishtown-analytics

Thank you for any help/ideas on this.

I am using Snowflake and dbt CLI, with Fivetran as the orchestrator

I added a profile called dev to my profiles.yml and put in all the connection details

profiles.yml now looks like this

```
default:
  target: prod
  outputs:
    prod:
      type: snowflake
      account: XYZ
      user: XYZ
      role: XYZ
      authenticator: XYZ
      database: ANALYTICS
      warehouse: XYZ
      schema: REPORTING
    dev:
      type: snowflake
      account: XYZ
      user: XYZ
      role: XYZ
      authenticator: XYZ
      database: ANALYTICS
      warehouse: XYZ
      schema: DEV_THEDRE
```

When I run the command `dbt run target prod -m model_name` there is no issue (my models get materialized into the schema called Reporting.

However, When I run the command `dbt run target dev -m model_name` , I get an error message:
`DEncountered an error: Runtime Error Database error while listing schemas in database "DEV" Database Error 002043 (02000): SQL compilation error: Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.`

However, there is no database called dev in my snowflake instance. I don't understand why its trying to find this database called "DEV".

I changed the name of the profile to **sand** to see if the word dev would be replaced for the word sand in the error message, but the error message still says "DEV"

The dbt logs file shows the following:

````
2021-10-17 20:37:54.100339 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Acquiring new snowflake connection "list_DEV".
2021-10-17 20:37:54.113467 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Using snowflake connection "list_DEV".
2021-10-17 20:37:54.113577 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): On list_DEV: /* {"app": "dbt", "dbt_version": "0.20.2", "profile_name": "default", "target_name": "dev", "connection_name": "list_DEV"} */

    show terse schemas in database DEV
    limit 10000
2021-10-17 20:37:54.113669 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Opening a new connection, currently in state init
2021-10-17 20:37:54.130004 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Loading KWallet
2021-10-17 20:37:54.131793 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Loading SecretService
2021-10-17 20:37:54.133543 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Loading Windows
2021-10-17 20:37:54.135003 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Loading chainer
2021-10-17 20:37:54.135968 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Loading macOS
2021-10-17 20:38:11.616136 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Snowflake query id: 019facf6-0601-3ffb-0038-1583017946a2
2021-10-17 20:38:11.617116 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Snowflake error: 002043 (02000): SQL compilation error:
Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.
2021-10-17 20:38:11.617625 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Error running SQL: macro list_schemas
2021-10-17 20:38:11.617828 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): Rolling back transaction.
2021-10-17 20:38:11.618305 (ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0): On list_DEV: Close
2021-10-17 20:38:11.918642 (MainThread): Connection 'master' was properly closed.
2021-10-17 20:38:11.918799 (MainThread): Connection 'list_DEV' was properly closed.
2021-10-17 20:38:11.919141 (MainThread): Sending event: {'category': 'dbt', 'action': 'invocation', 'label': 'end', 'context': [<snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x104d84400>, <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x104c9db50>, <snowplow_tracker.self_describing_json.SelfDescribingJson object at 0x104ca10d0>]}
2021-10-17 20:38:11.919411 (MainThread): Flushing usage events
2021-10-17 20:38:12.176058 (MainThread): Encountered an error:
2021-10-17 20:38:12.176328 (MainThread): Runtime Error
  Database error while listing schemas in database "DEV"
  Database Error
    002043 (02000): SQL compilation error:
    Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.```

Thank you once again!
````

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue
There was a macro that said
If target = Prod then database = defaultname ELSE database = dev
I changed it and its working now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).